# iOS change application's name and icon dynamically

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I have a Qt QML (5.9.9) application on iOS for which I need to change the name and icon dynamically.

There are a lot of posts on the subject but all date back to several years, so are not updated to new iOS version.

I found that it is possible to change the icon with the Objective-C function "setAlternateIconName" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname).

But for the name, I didn't find any recent post on it. So is it possible to do it or not? If yes, how?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: If you have an Objective C function that will accomplish it, you can always call it from QML using Objective-C++.